# Choosing between Debian and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, debian

Debian or Ubuntu for online multiplayer game cluster? (latest versions both)

I plan to run:

1. Erlang apps (ejabberd + modules) with many-many connection
2. Java apps for business logic
3. Memcached with about 32 GB
4. Heavily loaded postgresql 9.X
5. Some php stuff for front end.

Of course it will be distributed over 4-8 machines.

Have some experience with Debian - everything is great but software a little bit outdated...
Have very little ext with Ubuntu - runs like charm at the moment but heard that it has problems with many connections... (No idea if it is true, this is why I ask you.)

Comment: For Debian Squeeze there is also squeeze-backports repository if you need some more recent packages (http://backports.debian.org/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Do you want/need 'conservative' stability -> DEBIAN.
- Do you need latest software and are you willing to run maybe into some
  instability issue -> UBUNTU SERVER.

It is a matter of taste. Personally **I** would always **recommend** Debian as a Server OS anyday and the latest **-> Debian Squeeze** has most of the recent packages you would need since it has been released pretty recent.

I use it myself as a XEN virtualisation mothership running up to 6 Machines on it with a second backup machine synced via drbd. I am more than happy with it.

Answer (score 6):

I'd say Ubuntu Server LTS is a pretty good compromise between the stability of Debian and the 'latest and greatest' of the latest Ubuntu.

Comment: As in it tends to have more recent packages than a Debian that was released about the same time?

Comment: Yes, I believe so (at least compared to Debian Stable).

Comment: I was referring to Debian Stable when I said *a Debian that was released about the same time*. Also by *at least*, you are implying that it tends to happen that Ubuntu LTS offers later packages than other Debian suites (Testing/Unstable/Experimental).

Comment: Check the context and try a few different intonations when reading; you got your implication backwards.

Comment: I don't understand. What were you implying?

Comment: I was implying that Ubuntu LTS will almost always be more up-to-date than Debian Stable, but may or may not have more recent packages than Testing/Unstable/Experimental.

Comment: Okay. I was thrown by the fact that you screwed with the context when you mentioned *at least compared to Debian Stable*, because that's what we were talking about in the first place... *Debian Stable*.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu is effectively Debian testing with some specials on top and some bugfixes from Debian testing backported into it. Since the current release of Debian is quite new, you get fairly recent release of most packages. And there are also backports for the more important fixes. For a heavy duty server I would always go with Debian, especially if you already have experience with it.

Comment: More often than not, Ubuntu tales a snapshot of Debian unstable, not testing.